# Getting started with manipulating print meta-data

Tags: c#, .net, printing, xps

When sending a document, lets say TIFF images to a printer we can send meta-data with the image such as the paper size "Legal, Photo etc".  The printer is able to use this information to select a paper tray matching this paper size.

I have a program that generates a tif document and uses `PrintDocument` to generate a Print job.  This process occurs programmatically (no UI).  Is it possible to alter the metadata of the tif image programmatically before I send the job to the printer?

E.G. I want to change the paper size of the image to "Legal".  This way I can tell the printer which tray to use.  I have explored generating an XPS document out of the TIF. Then going back through a XPS API to set the property.  However, this solution feels a little heavy.  I hope for someone with more experience in this type of programming to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper size option is available in `PrintDocument`

```
private void SetPaperSize()
{
    int legalPaperIndex = 5;//See all types: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.papersize.rawkind.aspx
    for (int i = 0; i < printDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (printDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i].RawKind == legalPaperIndex)
        {
            printDocument.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = printDocument.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[i];
        }
    }    
}
```